# Is there a way to avoid calling a function multiple times in an 'elsif' branch?

Tags: ruby, conditional-statements, branch

I have a function that returns either `nil` or a non-`nil` value, and I use it in the following `if`-`else` clause:

```
if condition_that_doesnt_involve_my_func
  # do stuff
elsif my_func(cur_line)
  headers_found = my_func(cur_line)
end
```

I feel the above block is slightly wasteful because it calls the function twice and it could just save the result once and then use it in the following clause if the branch evaluates to non-`nil`.

Is there a way to rewrite this so that I only invoke the function once?

Comment: Do you only want to assign the returned value if the value is trueish or is it okay to also assign falsey values to headers_found?

Answer (score 2):

You can write:

```
elsif headers_found = my_func(cur_line)
```

I would not recommend that and Rubocop doesn't like that either.

Comment: I'm confused ... so you wouldn't recommend teh solution you just entered as an answer?  Is there a solution you would recommend?

Comment: Given you only provided a very short example this is the only way to make it even shorter. But I think it is not an improvement from a readability point of view. And it might lead to confusion because after an `if` you might expect a condition with a `==` but not an assignment with `=` (this is the offense Rubocop would complain about). Perhaps there might be a better way if you provide a longer example...

Comment: People always complain that I should put the simplest amount of code in my question so I try and keep it concise.  Still, I edited to put more detail.  Its not much, but really that's all I got.  It's pretty basic.  You see what I'm sayhing, right?  I don't want to call teh function any more times than I have to.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
if condition_that_doesnt_involve_my_func
  # do stuff
elsif answer = my_func(cur_line)
  headers_found = answer
end
```

Not sure if rubocop will bark at this. I don't use it.

Comment: YOu haven't saved anything though in the case where "condition_that_doesnt_involve_my_func" is true.  If taht is the case, your solution calls "my_func" once, whereas in the code I listed, it would never get called at all.

Comment: So spickermann was making that point as well.  Is the choice here basically I can have efficiency or readability but not both?  This example seems so basic, I would think there's a way to have both but I'm still a novice at this.

Comment: @Dave - This code adds an extra assignment only after the first `if` is falsy. In ruby this is way better than a method call in terms of overhead. Yes it's clunky. You have happened upon one of the nasty little corners of ruby. I think spickerman was trying to say that there might be another way around this given a bigger view of the code since it isn't something that comes up often. I know that you are trying to keep it concise. Sorry if it sounds like I'm being contradictory.

Answer (score 0):

If you are worry about it assign the return value to `headers_found`. It will ended up being false (`headers_found.present? #false`) or containing the headers.

```
if condition_that_doesnt_involve_my_func
  # do stuff
else 
  headers_found = my_func(cur_line)
end
```

Comment: Unfortunately I already have an "else" clause in my statement, which is why I had to use "elsif".

Comment: Hard to tell as I didn't see (... ). In any case you could add the call before the big if and reworked from there if you only want to invoke your function once. Ultimately you will want something readable.